# Команды между 2-мя UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется приложение с 2-мя Юзер контролами.1 - со списком пользователей, 2 - с историей сообщений.Также класс с набором методов.Как при нажатии на элемент(любой) из 1-го Юзер Контрола передать выполнение метода во 2-м.В метод желательно передать строку.Возможно даже определение методов в .cs файле контрола, но нужно запустить его выполнение и передать строку.Видел реализацию Command, но приложения крупные(для меня) и цепочка выполнения там не понятна мне.

Comment: Способов несколько. Через родительскую VM, через шину сообщений, через сервис-синглтон и подписки

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать источник с примером на родительскую VM? Да на любой способ вообще.Мне главное пример, а там я под себя постараюсь подстроить

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627819/parent-child-viewmodel-communication-in-wpf-prism-mvvm), [два](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807101/viewmodel-to-viewmodel-communication), [четыре](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286598/communicating-between-viewmodels-with-events), [пять](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-communication-among-viewmodels.html)